# Take only the first that satisfies the second condition in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a c# object with date field and foreign key. I have created one double index on these fields.

```
public class Session : DbObject
{        
    [DataMember]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Index(IsUnique = false, Order = 2)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Index(IsUnique = false, Order = 1)]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }     
}
```

I need to take a list from the 'Sessions' as follow: I have a list of patients ids and a date. I need to get one Session for each patient that its date is newest from all the rest.

something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessions WHERE PatientId IN (1, 2, ...) AND TOP(Date < SOME_DATE)
```

I know this query is nonsense. It just to clarify my intention.

***It is important to use the indexes because this table is huge.

If it is possible, I would like to know if I can write it in c# and entity framework.

I recently moved to MySQL. In MS SQL I could solve this with this query:

```
db.Sessions.FromSql(@"
with q as 
( 
   select Date, 
          PatientId, 
          row_number() over (partition by PatientId order by Date desc) rn
   where PatientId in (1,2,3,5,6,3)
     and Date > @d
   from Sessions
)
select Date, PatientId
from q
where rn = 1
", dt);
```

The problem that the WITH statement is not supported in mySQL in the version I'm using on AWS.
Please help to translate the query.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can just use GROUP BY, either in SQL Server or Mysql. The cte is not necessary:

```
  select
          PatientId, 
          MAX(`Date`) AS `Date`
   from Sessions
   where PatientId in (1,2,3,5,6,3)
   and Date > @d
   GROUP BY PatientId
```

Comment: I'm not sure this query has good performance like the one I have in the question. You must understand there are million of million of records in this table.

Comment: You can compare the execution plans and test the time. But from the code, this should have better performance because it removes the row_number function.